# webview using in android

Tags: android, webview

I am making a website and I am using delphi server. And I created webview in android. I take ip address.
like this code:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


    webView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");




}

}
```

its run.

but If I write webView.loadUrl("this is internet site address"); Now working actually not loading. I can not understand.

I am writting this ip(bla.bla.bla.bla:bla) its working on browser.So its loading web browser but not loading on android.

What is problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Give this permissions in `manifest.xml`.

```
    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <!-- Network State Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```